# Couldn't able to install ggpmisc in R Studio

Tags: r, ggpmisc

Couldn't able to install ggpmisc in R. Tried different combinations from previously reported suggestions but couldn't make it to work. Appreciate inputs.

Method 1:

```
install.packages("ggpmisc")
library(ggpmisc)
```

Console output:
Error in library(ggpmisc) : there is no package called ‘ggpmisc’

Method 2:

```
foldername <- 'C:/Users/xx00/R/win-library/4.0'
install.packages(paste(foldername, 'ggpmisc', sep = '/'),
                 repos = NULL, type = "source")
library(ggpmisc, lib.loc = 'C:/Users/xx00/R/win-library/4.0')
```

Console output:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xx00/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: invalid package 'C:/Users/xx00/R/win-library/4.0/ggpmisc'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/xx00/R/win-library/4.0/ggpmisc’ had non-zero exit status
> library(ggpmisc, lib.loc = 'C:/Users/xxoo/R/win-library/4.0')
Error in library(ggpmisc, lib.loc = "C:/Users/xxoo/R/win-library/4.0") : 
  there is no package called ‘ggpmisc’
```

Method 3:

```
download.packages('ggpmisc',destdir='C:/Users/xx00/R/win-library/4.0')
```

Output:

```
this downloaded tar.gz file but when manually extracted and saved it 
under the library didn't worked
```

Method 4:

```
pak::pkg_install("ggpmisc")
```

Console Output:

```
! rlang, vctrs, and tibble are loaded in other R sessions and have locked files
in your library. The installation will probably fail, unless you quit from this

R session:

* Rterm.exe (5336) in rstudio.exe (18316)

What do you want to do?

1. Quit these R sessions and try the installation again (Safest option.)
2. Terminate the listed R sessions. They may lose data!
3. Try the installation anyway.
4. Abort the installation.

? Your choice [1]: 3
i No downloads are needed, 17 pkgs (14.90 MB) are cached
i Building cli 3.6.1
Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
```

Comment: The errors are repeatedly saying that Rtools is not installed or found. [Install it](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). Once installed, ***restart R*** (and RStudio, if using it). Once restarted, try `install.packages("ggpmisc")` again. If that doesn't work, there will be lots of output after it that is likely meaningful and should be included in your question.

Comment: Other points: you cannot install a package from an existing R library (`C:/.../win-library/4.0`), it needs to be a tarball (`*.tar.gz` or `*.tgz`) for a source package or zip file (`*.zip`) for the binary version. You _should_ be installing the binary package onto windows, but you're on such an old/out-dated version of R that CRAN no longer supports it; unless you have specific reason to stay on a 3y-old version, I suggest updating to R-4.3.2. From there, installing it will be much faster as it will not require compiling (and therefore likely not Rtools either).

Comment: If after installing Rtools and restarting R, you attempt installation and it still fails, please [edit] your question, paste all of the text output from `install.packages("ggpmisc")` into a [code block], then @-ping me and we'll sort through the problem (which might be different from "Rtools not found"). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, found it very helpful. Updated R to the latest version which on itself worked for ggpmisc though I went ahead and installed the Rtools.

Comment: I'm really glad it worked for you! Good luck with R!